# Python logging root handler does not capture all

Tags: python, logging, configuration

I've got an issue with a root logger which I expected to work as a catch-all logger for anything that doesn't match other places. It's not working as I expected however. Here's a simplified logging configuration I use:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, specific

[handlers]
keys = syslog

[formatters]
keys = default

[logger_root]
level = WARNING
handlers = syslog

[logger_specific]
level = DEBUG
handlers = syslog
qualname = specific

[handler_syslog]
class = handlers.SysLogHandler
args = (('localhost',514), handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL0)
formatter = default

[formatter_default]
format = %(message)s
```

Now when I log anything from a module called `specific.something.else`, it gets logged properly. If I log from a `different.module`, I don't get that line at all. I can add more of the "specific" loggers and they capture the additional messages just fine... but how can I make the root logger a "catch-all" one? I was under the impression that it should do that role by default.

Comment: Are you sure the child-loggers are propagating records upwards up to the root logger? [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your `different.module` loggers were created *before* the `fileConfig` call, which results in those loggers being disabled in the call.

You need to ensure that you call `fileConfig` with `disable_existing_loggers=False`, and be running Python 2.6 or later so that you can use this keyword argument. If you can't do this, you'll need to avoid creating any loggers (other than those which are named, or whose ancestors are named, in the configuration) until *after* `fileConfig` has been called.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608717/incompatibility-between-import-time-logger-naming-with-logging-configuration).